# existing swf mp4 player?

Tags: actionscript, flash, mp4

I have a mp4 file put in my website, say http://example.com/a.mp4, I want a swf player that can be embedded into my html, and play the mp4 file. I don't know how to write actionscript so I just want to have an existing swf file.

Requirement: small, fancy, full function, ad free.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of players available, for example http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/ or http://flowplayer.org/.

Answer (score 6):

I was recently looking for a simple, robust, usable, non-branded swf video player to use as a flash fallback when using the HTML5 `<video>` element, and I found the [Strobe Media Playback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FMPSMP/Dev/WS3fd35e178bb08cb34f377935129f1474d5d-7ffc.html) player from Adobe. It fills all those requirements, and is fairly feature-rich. The files are directly downloadable from their [Sourceforge directory](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smp.adobe/files/). Here, more or less, is how I use it:

```
<video controls poster="video.jpg">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="StrobeMediaPlayback.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="StrobeMediaPlayback.swf">
        <param name="flashvars" value="src=video.mp4&amp;poster=video.jpg">
        <img src="video.jpg" alt="Video">
        <p>Your browser can’t play HTML5 or flash video. <a href="video.mp4">Download it</a> instead.</p>
    </object>
</video>
```

It supports lots of parameters specifiable from within the `flashvars` parameter, such as `autoplay` and a whole host of parameters related to the controls (the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FMPSMP/Dev/index.html) lists them).