# Simple Html5 code with error

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video

I have a simple html page with video player, which shows mp4 file. For those who doesn't support html5  tag and doesn't support this format video .mp4. I need play this video by flash player.

```
<video width="800" height="600" poster="kinopoisk2013.png" controls='controls'> 
<video src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k" width="800" height="600" controls='controls' > 
    <source src="kinopoisk2013.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <p>Your browser can’t play HTML5 video. <a href="kinopoisk2013.mp4"> Download it</a> instead.</p>
</video>
```

How i can play mp4 local video file by flash player?

Adding

1)

```
<object data="flvplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <param value="flvplayer.swf" name="movie"/>
</object>
```

but what the data and the value, where me add my file:'kinopoisk2013.mp4'

2) microsoft

```
   <object>
      <embed src=kinopoisk2013.mp4" type= "application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="always" />
   </object>
```

Example from microsoft. it's dont work too

3) opera

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="m/player.swf"
width="854" height="504">
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.mp4">
  <!--[if IE]><param name="movie" value="player.swf"><![endif]-->
  <img src="video.jpg" width="854" height="480" alt="Video">
  <p>Your browser can’t play HTML5 video. <a href="video.webm">Download
  it</a> instead.</p>
</object>
```

what the data, file? what the , why?

Comment: You say `Your browser can’t play HTML5 video.` but you are trying to play a flash video?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code with flash backup to support video on older devices

```
<video controls poster="video.jpg" width="854" height="480">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf" width="854" height="504">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.mp4">
    <!--[if IE]><param name="movie" value="player.swf"><![endif]-->
    <img src="video.jpg" width="854" height="480" alt="Video">
  <p>No video playback compatibility. <a href="video.webm">Download it</a> instead.</p>
 </object>
</video>
```

More details can be found in this article at Opera Dev http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/simple-html5-video-flash-fallback-custom-controls/

Comment: can you explain me, where i can find data="player.swf", 
it's need to be in the same derectory there html file? 

And why this <!--[if IE]><param name="movie" value="player.swf"><![endif]-->

Comment: Player you can get here http://sourceforge.net/projects/smp.adobe/files/ details can be read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787951/existing-swf-mp4-player

Comment: [if IE] is a conditional comment interpreted by MS IE and first introduced in IE 5. It is used to provide extra code to IE that is hidden from other browsers or vice versa.

Comment: i don't know. Html video play - ok; flash - don't play, flash player seen, but don't playing local files